# Problem compiling self-created header file using Dev-C++?

Tags: c, compilation, header-files, dev-c++

I am using Dev-C++ on windows vista. I have 3 files located in the same directory. They are:

```
- math_functions.h
- math_functions.c
- test3.c
```

math_functions.h code:

```
int   sum       (int x, int y);
float average   (float x, float y, float z);
```

math_functions.c code:

```
int sum (int x, int y)
{
  return (x + y);
}

float average (float x, float y, float z)
{
  return (x + y + z) / 3;
}
```

test3.c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math_functions.h"

main ()
{
  int   theSum     = sum (8, 12);
  float theAverage = average (16.9, 7.86, 3.4);

  printf ("the sum is: %i ", theSum);
  printf ("and the average is: %f \n", theAverage);
  printf ("average casted to an int is: %i \n", (int)theAverage);
}
```

It fails to compile. The error message I get is:

```
C:\Users\eSum\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKmdaaa.o(.text+0x3a) In function `main': 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `sum' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `average' 
C:\Users\eSum\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKmdaaa.o(.text+0x3a) ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use the same exact code compile in ubuntu(I run ubuntu using virtual machine i,e. vmplayer), it compiled without errors.

Do I need to set anything in Dev-C++ to compile the files?

Comment: Please don't use Dev-C++: http://www.jasonbadams.net/20081218/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/

Comment: Hi Karl, what do you use for C/C++ development? I am new, just started C/C++ today. My lecturer does not limit what software we can use. Any cool recommendation IDE(most important: "easy to compile") for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev-C++ seems not to be linking math_function.c with test3.c when making text3.exe this is a configuration problem in Dev-C++ you most likely need to add math_function.c to the Dev-C++ project

Comment: i haven't used that thing for years, and would rather use cygwin or msys

Comment: Cygwin or msys? If I am not wrong, I write the C/C++ codes in any code editor, and then open the command line (CMD in windows) and compile, is that right?

Comment: yes, exactly; both of those provide gcc and make, although msys's gcc doesn't link everything to libcygwin1

Comment: Thanks. I will use notepad++ as the code editor and cygwin as the compiler =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the header-file, but with your project settings. You have to add math_functions.c to the project so it gets compiled and linked with test3.c.